# Why does Resolve-DnsName return completely different columns on different machines?

Tags: windows, powershell

When executing this script on my Windows 10 computer, I get the following results:

`Resolve-DnsName -Name "www.idg.se" -Server 8.8.8.8 -Type NS`

```
Name                        Type TTL   Section    PrimaryServer               NameAdministrator           SerialNumber
----                        ---- ---   -------    -------------               -----------------           ------------
idg.se                      SOA  900   Authority  ns-634.awsdns-15.net        awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.co 1           
                                                                              m
```

When executing the same script on my Windows Server 2019 I get this output:

```
Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost                                                                                                          
idg.se                         NS     21600 Answer     ns-1452.awsdns-53.org                                                                                             
idg.se                         NS     21600 Answer     ns-1691.awsdns-19.co.uk                                                                                           
idg.se                         NS     21600 Answer     ns-192.awsdns-24.com                                                                                              
idg.se                         NS     21600 Answer     ns-634.awsdns-15.net
```

PS version on computer:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                     
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1682                                                                                                                                            
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                   
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                   
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1682                                                                                                                                           
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                           
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                       
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

PS version on server:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                     
----                           -----                                                                                                                                     
PSVersion                      5.1.17763.2931                                                                                                                            
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                   
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                   
BuildVersion                   10.0.17763.2931                                                                                                                           
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                           
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                       
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                       
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

It is nearly the same version. I would expect the same column names to be returned.

Update: I just installed Powershell 7 on the server. The output is exactly the same way as in Powershell 5.1.

Comment: Read following : https://codingbee.net/powershell/powershell-changing-a-command-outputs-default-formatting

Comment: @jdweng This is information about formatting as far as I understand. The problem for me is that the "PrimaryServer" column doesn't exist at all on my server. It displays nothing if I use " | Select PrimaryServer" for instance.

Comment: That is not the question you asked.  You really have two issues.  One if the formatting and the other is why some values are not set.  Try from cmd.exe >IPCONFIG/ALL which give info in a format that tells which interface the parameters are located.

Comment: The question is why PowerShell acts completely different on different machines when using the same code. It would be like typing "2+2" and you get "result:4" on one machine and "answer:4" on another. This means I have to write two different scripts depending on how the results are outputted. I just want the output to be consistent so I can reuse the script. How am I supposed to do something with the PrimaryServer column if it doesn't exist because the data is stored in a column named something completely different?

Comment: Test for the OS when running the script and/or use a conditional. It's not that hard to code around and you can post a bug report for it too if you like....

Comment: @Scepticalist sure, If the OS is the reason for this, I could do it. But it is only a workaround. I have to reevaluate if PowerShell is the right way forward. PowerShell even lacks a full documentation of the Resolve-DnsName command. It only describes the input parameters but nothing else.

Comment: I’ve not tried this myself, but I’m pretty sure different record types have different properties. Your first example is an ```SOA``` record but your second only contains ```NS``` records. I suspect if you resolve a domain that has ```NS``` records on the first server you’ll see a ```NameHost``` column, and if you return an ```SOA``` record on the second server you’ll see a ```PrimaryServer``` column. You can possibly confirm this by calling ```.GetType().FullName``` on each record and seeing what class name is returns.

Comment: @mclayton You are correct! Please consider posting this as an answer, and I will mark it as a solution.